# Cannot type Japanase kanji from windows IME into oracle 12c database sqlplus in windows 10

Tags: oracle, unicode, utf-8, windows-10, ime

my column,"ideograph", is of varchar2(1000) datatype. I inserted one character into the column with Microsoft IME, 寺, Oracle sqlplus just gives me a "?".
  I checked v$nls_parameters.
  nls_characterset= AL32UTF8
  nls_nchar_characterset= AL16UTF16

Now,based on what i've read in other questions here, if I'm using varchar2 datatype, then based on the v$nls_parameters query, the db is using AL32UTF8, but this is a " national characterset", I think, I have no idea what is the " database" character set is.

I also used the dump function with the dual table.
  select dump('寺',1016) from dual;
 I got typ=96 len=1 characterset=AL32UTF8: 3F

I did the same thing in livesql.oracle.com, which uses apex on a cloud, and I got this:
    typ=96 len=3 characterset=AL32UTF8: e5,af,ba

why the hexadecimal codes are different if it says is the same character set?

I have no idea what encoding microsoft IME is using, maybe that is the problem.

How can I fix this? I can create another database, because I don't have any data in the one I'm doing this, is just for training purposes. but I want to see if I can fix it without having to do that.

Comment: AL32UTF8 is Oracle naming for Unicode. To have NLS settings working for a local database you should understand **NLS_LANG** setting (this is an OS setting not an Oracle instance or session parameter): see https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/faq-nls-lang.html.

Comment: So you are saying that I have to go to the windows 10 settings , find this NLS_LANG parameter and change the unicode character set to AL32UT8? that way the microsoft IME will match with oracle?

Comment: Yes; you should check what is your NLS_LANG setting.  But the right settings depends on your Windows regional settings, how your application works with Oracle regarding NLS. Note also that it is possible that the right NLS_LANG can be different  for SQLPlus in character mode, for SQL Developer (Oracle tool - GUI in Java) or for your application IME. Character set AL32UTF8 may work or maybe you should choose the one specific to your Windows regional settings (japanese ? chinese ?).

Comment: thankyou pifor, i will look into that.

Comment: pifor, I read that link you posted, I changed the nls_lang parameter in the windows registry like they said, it was American_America.WE8MSWIN1252. I just changed the characterset part, into: American_America.JA16SJIS. That did not work.

Comment: pifor, I read that link you posted, I changed the nls_lang parameter in the windows registry like they said, it was American_America.WE8MSWIN1252. I just changed the characterset part, into: American_America.JA16SJIS. That did not work. Then I changed it to " Japanese_Japan.JA16SJIS", that also did not work.  I changed the ACP code from 1252 to 932 which corresponds to JA16SJIS, but this is for some GUI sqlplus, which i'm not using, I'm using command prompt sqlplus, so they say change the OEM, i changed this to 932 also, still when I type kanji into sqlplus,is not working.

Comment: Sorry but I cannot help more.

Comment: I got it now, i forgot to mention that I was using sqlplus with powershell. The regular prompt in powershell " c prompt" was not set in the appropiate code page. I did chcp 65001, and then I could type in Japanese. I want to give pifor that he answered the question, i'm trying to figure out how to do that.  thanyou pifor.

Comment: Glad it eventually worked.

Answer (score 0):

General solution is learning NLS_LANG setting in Oracle and understanding that you may have different NLS_LANG settings on Windows because Windows command line mode does not work the same way as Windows graphical user interface as far as character set settings are concerned.